# "..didn't mind X's belief"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I thought this was a common phrase, but Google returns very few results: [mind my belief](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22didn%27t%20mind%20my%20belief%22&oq=%22didn%27t%20mind%20my%20belief%22&gs_l=serp.3...1120.4528.0.5030.5.4.1.0.0.0.171.564.0j4.4.0....0...1.1.64.serp..4.1.169.PHSgaiGpU_s), [mind his belief](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22didn%27t%20mind%20his%20belief%22&oq=%22didn%27t%20mind%20his%20belief%22&gs_l=serp.3...11309.11510.0.11567.3.3.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.serp..3.0.0.rMrb_YvJTkE), [mind her belief](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22didn%27t%20mind%20her%20belief%22&oq=%22didn%27t%20mind%20her%20belief%22&gs_l=serp.3...44813.44983.0.45066.3.3.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.serp..3.0.0.t_rqpR9F7Xc).

Example sentence:

> For my part I didn't mind my mother's belief. In fact, I was glad she had
>   found it.

Why is this? Is there a more common version?

Comment: "Didn't mind" meaning "didn't object to" is common. Trying to find a quote specifying exactly what was not objected to will not be easy.

Comment: Also, one does not typically "find beliefs", but rather one "finds religion", "finds Jesus" (for Christianity specifically), etc. I suppose "faith" would be an improvement over "belief" in your sentence, though I'd still find it awkward (just less awkward).

Comment: @DanBron - Where do you get 'find' from?  The question is about 'mind'.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Second to last word of the quoted passage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll expand Andrew Leach's comment into an answer.

> [mind](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mind)
>
> verb : to be bothered by (something) : to object to or dislike
>   (something)
>
> : to care about or worry about (something or someone)
>
> —used to make a polite request
>
> *Merriam Webster*

---

To see examples, follow the links at the bottom of this [Google ngram: didn't mind](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%20didn%27t%20mind%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdid%20not%20mind%3B%2Cc0)

Note: Click the *Search lots of books* button to get the full listing.

**Answer**

> For my part I didn't **mind** my mother's belief. In fact, I was glad she had found it.

This means

> For my part I didn't **object to** my mother's belief. In fact, I was glad she had found it.